# Convert UTC to Local Timezone in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, timezone, converters, utc

how to convert UTC to local time with Oracle PL/SQL? My data provider send me following:

```
    <EndDateTime>"2016-09-26T08:00:00Z"</EndDateTime>
```

and I would like to convert it to "Berlin" Time. I've searched here for an answer, but it is quite difficult to find the right answer.

Comment: Are you getting strings from your data provider?

Comment: also what version of oracle are you using?

Comment: * I get an XML File
* Oracle Version 12.1.0.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like that should help You:

```
SELECT 
    FROM_TZ(
        CAST(
            TO_DATE('2000-01-01T11:00:00Z','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH:MI:SS"Z"') AS TIMESTAMP
        ), 'Greenwich'
    ) AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin' 
    as converted_timestamp
FROM DUAL;
```

Where *2000-01-01T11:00:00Z* is Your date and *'Greenwich'* is timezone of the date You receive and *'Europe/Berlin'* is the timezone You want to convert to.

And some references: [one](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1007699), [two](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13866_04/webconf.904/b10877/timezone.htm) and [three](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions059.htm).

Comment: Nowadays you say `UTC`, `Greenwich` is a bit "old style".